# What is the smallest prime of the form $n^n+8$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

- Is there a prime of the form $n^n+8$ , $n\in \mathbb N$ ?
- If yes, what is the smallest one ?

It is clear, that $n$ must be odd and cannot be a multiple of $3$ (otherwise
$n^n+8$ is of the form $x^3+8=(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$ and both $x+2$ and $x^2-2x+4=(x-1)^2+3$ are greater than $1$, so $n^n+8$ is not prime).

Furthermore, I verified that $n^n+8$ is composite for all natural numbers
below $4000$.

Comment: It is an interesting question (+1), however did you really verified that $3997^{3997}+8$ is a composite number ? If yes, how did you do it ? Because it has a lot of digits...

Comment: $3997^{3997}+8$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: It is also divisible by 3.

Comment: @Dylan, ok thank you. Peter, Do all integers $n^n+8$ have small divisors like $3997^{3997}+8$ ?

Comment: We can at least tell (by examining modulo $2$ and $3$) that $n$ must be congruent to $5$ modulo $6$.

Comment: Of course, I checked the primality with a computer! It would be hopeless to check such large numbers, unless they have very small factors. The factors can be so large, that they are virtually out of reach, but there is an efficient method for checking primality (without knowing any factor!)

Comment: $35^{35}+8$ is the first one with large factors.  490980651167 is the smallest factor and there are two bigger factors.

Comment: What about numbers of the form $^nn+1$? Is that even remotely calculable?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First I checked that there were no primes up to $10^4$ using [PFGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/). As expected, there were no primes.

Then I considered a rough heuristic: $n^n+8$ is prime with probability $1/\log(n^n).$ Since
$$
\int\frac{dx}{x\log x}
$$
diverges, you expect infinitely many primes unless something odd happens where all residue classes are ruled out. But this seems unlikely: $21^{21}+8$ has no prime factors below 1801088543, and so you'd need ridiculously long periods to cover the residue classes containing 21.

Looking at the residue classes of the primes up to 17 (this requires working mod 4084080) I find that 5248/36465 of the congruence classes are available for primes, each of which (by virtue of generating numbers relatively prime to 2, 3, ..., 17) is ~5.5394 times more likely to be prime than a typical number of its size. A little bit of summation together with Poisson magic gives a ~16% chance of finding a prime of this form with $n$ from $10^4$ to $10^5$. If that sounds worthwhile, I suggest continuing the calculation to this region -- it would require a few days on a decent machine, nothing crazy.

For comparison, the expected number of primes with $n$ up to $10^{100}$ is about 2.6, so if you get a universe-sized computer and run it for the age of the universe you should be able to find a prime with decent (~92%) probability.

Comment: +1 interesting study. If I have the budget to build the universe-sized computer, I'll build one to find the question for answer 42 first ;-)

Comment: @achillehui, no need:  [42 is the answer to the question “what is (-80538738812075974)³ + 80435758145817515³ + 12602123297335631³?”](https://aperiodical.com/2019/09/42-is-the-answer-to-the-question-what-is-80538738812075974³-80435758145817515³-12602123297335631³).