# What is the smallest prime of the form $n^n+5$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305251/what-is-the-smallest-prime-of-the-form-nn8) question asks about the smallest prime of the form $n^n+8$. However, I haven't be able to find a prime of the form $n^n+5$ where $n$ is natural, assuming we take $0^0=1$.

If $n$ is odd, then $n^n+5$ is even. If $n \equiv 2 \mod 6$ or $n \equiv 4 \mod 6$ then $n$ is even and $\gcd(n,3)=1$ and hence by the Euler-Fermat theorem $n^n \equiv 1 \mod 3$, and hence $n^n+5 \equiv 0 \mod 3$.

So only numbers in the form $n=6m$ can qualify. Of course, one also needs that $n$ is not divisible by 5. I also checked $n \leq 71$, they are not prime.

So I wonder whether there exists a prime in the form $n^n+5$, and if so, what is the smallest?

Comment: $144^{144}+5$ seems to be the first not divisible by small primes (among which $67$ and $83$ seem to occur quite often), but it is still composite ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes! It is divisible by $12{,}090{,}863$. This can be found quickly with the following naïve PARI/GP program: `forprime(p=2,,Mod(144,p)^144+5==0&&print(p))` It runs through all primes $p$ from $p=2$ and up and checks if the ellement $144$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $x^{144}+5\equiv 0$ and if so, goes on to `print(p)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$444^{444}+5$ is prime, and is the smallest of that form.  The next is $3948^{3948}+5$.

`perl -Mntheory=:all -Mbigint -E 'for (1..1e5) { say if is_prime((0+$_)**$_+5); }'`

It's a little faster using `-Mbigint=lib,GMP` or `-MMath::GMP=:constant`.  A bit under 0.3 seconds to find the first, albeit this is uses a robust PRP test rather than doing a proof.

See:  [factordb entry](http://factordb.com/index.php?query=444%5E444%2B5) for a primality certificate.

Comment: I suppose you didn't find this manually.How did you do it?

Comment: @user254665, I added the one-liner I used.  It will keep going looking for more, and of course gets slower as they grow.  You could do the same with Pari/GP, Mathematica, etc.

Comment: $444^{444}+5$ It is gigantic. However THE NEXT is 3948. You have to edit I guess.

Comment: I guess I thought it was clear that 3948 referred to $n$, not the number itself.

Comment: Why $n^n+5$? Why not $n^n+$something else?

Comment: Good question.  Probably should be a comment on the question.

Comment: @user254665 Primes in the form $n^n+k$ for $k=1,2,3,4,6,7$ are trivial to find. The question I linked in the question asks for $k=8$. So I was wondering about $k=5$, which I couldn't find.

Comment: A search for k=8 I tried gave me nothing to n=20k.  k=11 and 17 are also not trivial.  Some others have one or two tiny results then nothing else small.